# Oppo Realme1 Job Schduler Min interval for Periodic Work is 1 hr

Tags: android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher, android-workmanager, android-job

Currently I am using `WorkManager 1.0.0-alpha05`. I set periodic Work Request using below `code`. 
When interval is below 1 hr then In `Oppo Realme` (Android Version - 8.1.0 , `ColorOSVersion V5.0`) 
job execute at `1` hr. When interval greater than `1` hr job execute at exact time . when interval is smaller than `1` hr then job execute at `1` hr.

Please let me know any log or information required :

**Code For Schdule Periodic Job:**

```
PeriodicWorkRequest uploadWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.
                Builder(LocationUpdatesJobService.class ,interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addTag(Constants.Location.TAG_BACKGROUND_LOCATION_PERIODIC)
                .setConstraints(constraints).build();
            WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                    Constants.Location.TAG_BACKGROUND_LOCATION_PERIODIC,
                    ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, uploadWork);
```

in all other device Periodic Work request interval is proper. In Oppo Realme 1 work execute at `1` hr.

**Oppo Realme 1: Interval 15 Min**

I debug Job Schduler using below command: 
`adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler`

```
JOB #u0a249/18: cc2fc59 com.cygneto.field_sales/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
u0a249 tag=job/com.cygneto.field_sales/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
Source: uid=u0a249 user=0 pkg=com.cygneto.field_sales
JobInfo:
Service: com.cygneto.field_sales/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
PERIODIC: interval=+1h0m0s0ms flex=+21m0s0ms
Requires: charging=false batteryNotLow=false deviceIdle=false
Extras: mParcelledData.dataSize=180
Backoff: policy=1 initial=+30s0ms
Has early constraint
Has late constraint
Required constraints: TIMING_DELAY DEADLINE
Satisfied constraints: APP_NOT_IDLE DEVICE_NOT_DOZING
Unsatisfied constraints: TIMING_DELAY DEADLINE
Doze whitelisted: true
Tracking: TIME
Enqueue time: -9m4s617ms
Run time: earliest=+29m55s383ms, latest=+50m55s383ms
Ready: false (job=false user=true !pending=true !active=true !backingup=true comp=true)
```

**Oppo Realme 1: Interval 1hr 10  Min**

**Log:**

```
JobInfo:
Service: com.cygneto.field_sales/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
PERIODIC: interval=+1h10m0s0ms flex=+1h10m0s0ms
Requires: charging=false batteryNotLow=false deviceIdle=false
Extras: mParcelledData.dataSize=180
Doze whitelisted: true
Tracking: TIME
Enqueue time: -4m19s846ms
Run time: earliest=+1h5m39s833ms, latest=+2h15m39s833ms
Last successful run: 2018-07-25 17:01:23
Ready: false (job=false user=true !pending=true !active=true !backingup=true comp=true)
```

**Other Device :**

**Log :**

```
JobInfo:
Service:com.cygneto.field_sales/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
    PERIODIC: interval=+15m0s0ms flex=+15m0s0ms
    Requires: charging=false batteryNotLow=false deviceIdle=false
    Tracking: TIME
    Enqueue time: -29s237ms
    Run time: earliest=+14m30s690ms, latest=+29m30s690ms
    Last successful run: 2018-07-25 17:29:19
    Ready: false (job=false user=true !pending=true !active=true !backingup=true comp=true)
```

I also try Using different library. I found same behavior in Job Scheduler  and Android-Job.
job period length is 15 min but execute at 1 hr but when i try using firebase job dispatcher
job execute at correct 15 min interval time.

i debug Job Scheduler and Android-Job using below command:
**adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler**

**Job Scheduler:**

**Interval** : 15 Min 
**Output**   : 1 hr

**Log:**

```
JOB #u0a266/1: a0dd846 com.jobscheduler_periodic/com.periodic.JobSchedulerService
    u0a266 tag=*job*/com.jobscheduler_periodic/com.periodic.JobSchedulerService
    Source: uid=u0a266 user=0 pkg=com.jobscheduler_periodic
    JobInfo:
      Service: com.jobscheduler_periodic/com.periodic.JobSchedulerService
      PERIODIC: interval=+1h0m0s0ms flex=+15m0s0ms
```

**Android-Job:**

**Interval** : 15 Min 
**Output** :  1 hr:

**Log:**

```
JOB #u0a266/3: 10c0d65 com.jobscheduler_periodic/com.evernote.android.job.v21.PlatformJobService
    u0a266 tag=*job*/com.jobscheduler_periodic/com.evernote.android.job.v21.PlatformJobService
    Source: uid=u0a266 user=0 pkg=com.jobscheduler_periodic
    JobInfo:
      Service: com.jobscheduler_periodic/com.evernote.android.job.v21.PlatformJobService
      PERIODIC: interval=+1h0m0s0ms flex=+5m0s0ms
```

**Firebase Job Dispatcher:**

I debug firebase job Dispatcher using below command:
**adb shell "dumpsys activity service GcmService | grep com.jobscheduler_periodic"**

**Interval** : 15 Min 
**Output** : 15 min

**Log**:

```
u0|com.jobscheduler_periodic: 1
    (scheduled) com.jobscheduler_periodic/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver{u=0 tag="MyJobService" trigger=window{s
tart=720s,end=900s,earliest=46s,latest=226s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED,CHARGING] attributes=[RECURRING] scheduled=-673s last_
run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=FIREBASE_JOB_DISPATCHER-1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to be an OEM bug. Unfortunately, it is very hard to work around these kind of bugs, in a battery efficient way. If you want a period of 15 mins, I suggest using the following workaround:

Use a `OneTimeWorkRequest` instead of a periodic work request, and upon first execution of the first work request, schedule a second from inside the worker with an `initialDelay` of `15 mins`. That will essentially give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried using OneTimeWorkRequest and its working fine. But i don't understand when i try periodic job using firebase job dispatcher job execute at correct time . internally firebase job dispatcher not schedule job using job scheduler? in job scheduler, android-job when periodic job less than 1 hr (15,20 minute) job execute at 1 hr in oppo realme except firebase job dispatcher.

Comment: `FirebaseJobDispatcher` uses `GCMNetworkManager` behind the scenes. It does not use `JobScheduler`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I  will  try WorkManager with  FirebaseJobDispatcher (android.arch.work:work-firebase) .I  will check  when use WorkManager with FirebaseJobDispatcher  than  work execute at 15 Min interval or 1 hours in oppo realme 1?.  so if i use WorkManager with FirebaseJobDispatcher  than all schedule of task using GCMNetworkManager correct ?

Comment: WorkManager will only use FJD if SDK_LEVEL <= 22. So for API 23 and up, it will always use JobScheduler.

Comment: Thanks for Answer all my doubt related  FirebaseJobDispatcher ,JobScheduler, WorkManager are cleared.